# Вопросы по настройке pom.xml и mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, maven

Пишу свое первое CRUD+Spring MVC+Hibernate приложение. Скачал проект на одном из обучающих сайтов и открыл в IDEA. Обнаружил, что IDE ругается на 2 вещи:

1. в `pom.xml` в строке `<webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>` теги выделены красным и всплывающая надпись "Element webXml is not allowed here"
2. в `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` в строке `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` `"/resources/"` выделено красным и всплывающая надпись "Cannot resolve location"

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ranga</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring4Hiberante4Integration</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Spring4Hiberante4Integration</name>

<!-- Specifying the Versions of Spring, Hiberante, MySQL etc -->
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.10</mysql.version>
    <junit-version>4.11</junit-version>
    <servlet-api-version>3.1.0</servlet-api-version>
    <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<!-- Specifying the Dependencies -->
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--MYSQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet and JSP -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId> 
        <version>${servlet-api-version}</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp-version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>Spring4Hiberante4Integration</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service, 
    DAO -->
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.ranga" />

<!-- Getting Database properties -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driverClass}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${connection.acquireIncrement}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${connection.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${connection.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${connection.maxIdleTime}" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ranga.entity"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Spring4 MVC Hibernate4 Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем беда? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Уберите скриншоты и оформите вопрос с кодом. Покажите pom.xml и web.xml

Comment: Владимир, код добавил.

Comment: где находится resources?

Comment: @svorobei скиньте ссылку, откуда качали исходники.

Comment: resources находится в src\main, я пробовал писать src\main\resources - не помогло..

Comment: Создал папку /src/main/webapp/resources и переместил туда! naiad09 Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Папка для

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

должна ссылаться на `/src/main/webapp/resources`. Это ресурсы, которые использует веб приложение для работы в браузере - стили, скрипты, картинки. Используя эту настройку, мы открываем браузеру доступ к этим статическим ресурсам напрямую, всего лишь через маппинг. В соседнем `WEB-INF` лежат ресурсы, которым такая роскошь недопустима. А `src/main/resources` - это ресурсы приложения, неободимые для его выполнения, конфиги то бишь, `xml` и `.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, собственно, и отвечаю на свой вопрос)

По первому пункту убрал теги `<executions>` и `<execution>`. Оставил только `<configuration>` и ошибка исчезла.

Во втором пункте оставил все как есть. Проект запустился и работает. Почему IDE ругается на resources пока непонятно :/